# How can get ad image data without for, but with a custom ID prop?

Tags: python

I want to manage a list of image in a collection, but I need to search the image in bpy.images.data, but is a Panel class, so it make a lot of refresh.
I've create a ID prop to bpy.type.Image, so each image ave a unique ID wich I assign in other process.
The collections prop have the ID of the image, bat the only way is to make a for:

```
name = "no image"
images = bpy.data.images
if bpy.context.scene.paintPBR_index > -1:
    for img in images:
        if img.id_pbrpainter == layer.image_ID and img.id_pbrpainter != 0:
            #print("get_image")
            name = img.name

    return name
```

There is a way to search the image in bpy.data.images by the custom prop?

Comment: Can you expand on the code,  The code you posted will only return the name of the last matching image.  Later versions of blender allow an object reference to be saved in a groupproperty, could be useful in this case, I think.

Comment: Are you saying about the 2.8?

Comment: Available in 2.79 [The example here uses `bpy.types.Object`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87980/15543) whereas you would use image type.