# blender python ShaderNodeTexImage subclass does not inherit parent's properties?

Tags: python

what I am trying to do is registering my own image user (for node customization). Basically, I am trying to create a custom node group that can be an image user. Placing 'ShaderNodeTexImage' node into its node tree is not an option - the class itself must be able to hold the image and the image_user attributes. So, I attempted:

```
class experimental(bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage):
    bl_label = "this is experimental"

bpy.utils.register_class(experimental)

bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new(type = 'experimental')
```

This does create a new node and register the class with no mistakes but I try

```
bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.active.[autocomplete]
```

it does not show the Image property (my subclass does not inherit the properties of the ShaderNodeTexImage). Why???

is there any other way to create an .image and .image_user properties for my custom class? in the ideal world, I would like to have something like:

```
class myClass(bpy.types.Node):

    img = bpy.types.Image(params)
    img_user = bpy.types.ImageUser(params)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Check out the custom nodes template in text editor.

Comment: @batFINGER sorry, but I think, if one knows the answer, it would take 2 sentences to formulate it. at the first glance, custom_nodes.py has nothing to help me.

Comment: _I think_ you need to take more than a first glance.  For instance  a registered class property in blender is never going to be `img = bpy.types.Image(params)` (_do you think you can even instance an image that way in blender?_) more likely would use `img = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Image)`  Have no idea what the 2 sentences blah re my comment (yes a comment not an answer)  is about.... don't think I want to know.

Comment: @batFINGER no intention to insult you. of course I do know that bpy.types.Image(params) does not work - that was a syntactical example of what I would like to have. regarding PointerProperty: the pointer property type input must only be a sublass of PropertyGroup, whereby the PropertyGroup itself does not allow anything fancy. It's a mere container for palin properties.

Comment: BS [The pointer property type can be an ID type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84550/save-objects-in-object-id-properties-blender-2-79). Also  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/556/pynodes-the-bare-basics

Comment: @batFINGER cool! I was reading an old documentation :/ probably I can now go on with it, thanks a lot! feel free to publish an answer if you will